# How do I get Custom Attibutes from a assembly in Winrt

Tags: windows-runtime, system.reflection

I have:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[Foo]
public class Bar1
{
}

[Foo]
public class Bar2
{
}

[Foo]
public class Bar3
{
}
```

Then I do:

```
var attrs = CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Bar1).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

I had expeced that attrs should contain the Foo attribute,, but that is not true. Instead attrs contains 12 other attributes.

Whats wrong??

Comment: You are retrieving [assembly] attributes, not the attributes of the Bar1 class.  Sure, there are a bunch of them, not [Foo] of course.  Remove `.Assembly`.

Comment: If I remove it,, I only gets the attrubute from Bar1. What about Bar2 and Bar3?

Comment: If you want to find *all* of the types that have a this attribute then you have to enumerate the types in the assembly, Assembly.GetTypes().  Tough cookies on winrt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maby not plesant,,, but Hans answer workes for me.

> If you want to find all of the types that have a this attribute then you have to enumerate  the types in the assembly, Assembly.GetTypes(). Tough cookies on winrt. –  Hans Passant 20 hours ago